# Office.JS “This add-in is no longer available” error when creating a Word Document with context.application.createDocument()

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I'm developing an add-in for Microsoft Word 2016 using [office js version 16.0.8626.1000](https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js). I use a web service to retrieve a document in base64 format and then I create a new Word instance with that.

The problem is that whenever I run the add-in from my server (not from visual studio debugger) it opens the document but the add-in frame displays an error

First Instance:
[image: First office instance]

Second Instance:
[image: Second instance with document retrieved from WS]

This doesn't happen if I run the add-in from visual studio debugger, it opens the new instance without the frame.

This is my code

```js
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    // Checks for the DOM to load using the jQuery ready function.
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#get').click(function () {
            openWord();
        });
    });
}
```

This how I retrieve the document (without real url):

```js
function openWord() {
    getDocumentAsBase64(function (data) {
        Word.run(function (context) {
            var myNewDoc = context.application.createDocument(data);
            context.load(myNewDoc);

            return context.sync()
                .then(function () {
                    myNewDoc.open();
                    context.sync();
                })
                .catch(function (myError) {
                    //otherwise we handle the exception here!
                    updateStatus(myError.message);
                })
        }).catch(function (myError) {
            updateStatus(myError.message);
        });
    });
}

function getDocumentAsBase64(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://myurltomydocument.com/getFile',
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (response) {
            callback(response.d);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            updateStatus(response.d);
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT -- 8/12/2017

This is the [manifest](https://pastebin.com/vP7G8MQz) that I'm currently using if anyone wants to replicate the problem with Office 2016

Answer (score 0):

I don't read Spanish, but the error mentions Visual Studio. I think Office is still trying to run a version that was sideloaded with Visual Studio and it's telling you that it can't do that. The problem might be the manifest. I notice that it still has the string `~remoteAppUrl` in many places. When you are debugging with VS, this string is automatically replaced with the localhost URL, but you need to manually change all these to your web service's domain and sideload the new manifest when you are going to run it from the web service.

EDIT 12/11/17: 
If that doesn't fix it, try clearing the Office cache. Details are at: [Clear the Office cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-manifest#clear-the-office-cache)

Edit 12/19/17: 
Try this:
Go on **File**->**Info**->**Check for Issues** -> **Inspect Document** -> **Inspect**.
Then on **Task Pane Add-ins** click **Remove All**

Comment: Thanks for your response. Indeed the manifest I published here on pastebin has `~remoteAppUrl` (I didn't change it just to keep the server url private. On my local machine the url it's written correctly). So that's not the problem. I'm gonna edit the post with the real manifest, so you can replicate the problem.

Comment: Still the same. I´ve posted this issue on [MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/1be3f84b-3824-48d2-a180-5dff06b7f188/officejs-this-addin-is-no-longer-available-error-when-creating-a-word-document-with?forum=worddev) and someone told me that the problem is a bit complex, and that he was going to involve a senior engineer to this topic.

Thank you again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution to this problem.

1. First I downloaded [Office 2016 Administrative Template Files](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49030).
   When you run it, it will extract a bunch of files and folders.
2. Enter **admx** folder and copy the whole content to *C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions*.
3. Do a *gpupdate /force* under CMD (or Powershell) as an administrator.
4. Run gpedit.msc and find the Administrative Template for Office 2016 then Updates (PC configuration >> Administrative Template >> Microsoft Office 2016 >> Updates >> Update Channel) and set the Update Channel to *Montly Channel*.

I'm on Version 1711 (compilation 8730.2127 click and run) and everything is working good now.

EDIT 9/1/2018:
The error started showing up again. The only thing I did was attaching the runtime logging to debug my add-in manifest. This is still unsolved.